# Adding files to a directory

Tags: c

```
include <dirent.h>
include <stdio.h>

void printMatrixToFile(matrix_t inputMatrix, int gen, int signature, char* dirname) {
char filename[64];
sprintf(filename, "%d%s%d%s", signature, "_genNo.", gen, ".txt");
DIR* dir = opendir(dirname);
FILE *file = fopen(filename,"w");
fprintf(file,"%d %d\n", inputMatrix->x-2, inputMatrix->y-2);
for (int i = 1; i < inputMatrix->x-1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < inputMatrix->y-1; j++) {
        fprintf(file,"%c ", inputMatrix->macierz[i * inputMatrix->y + j]);
    }
    fprintf(file,"\n");
}
closedir(dir);
fclose(file);
}
```

Im creating .txt files and trying to add them to the directory.  Generating .txt is fine but they do not appear in the desired directory.

Comment: `char filename[64];
sprintf(filename, "%d%s%d%s", signature, "_genNo.", gen, ".txt");` **-->>** `char filename[PATH_MAX];
sprintf(filename, "/%s/%d%s%d%s", dirname, signature, "_genNo.", gen, ".txt");`  (and you dont need opendir())`

Comment: You never use `dir` except for closing. What do you think `DIR* dir = opendir(dirname);` does? Have you considered using a path for opening the output file?

Comment: @wildplasser :-) Two ways of saying the same.

Comment: @wildplasser i did as you told me and it doesn't work :(. dirname should be a path to the catalog, right?

Comment: Maybe I had a few slashes too many. And: you should not ask **me** what `dirname` means, it is your program... (and: what do you mean with *catalog* ?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `opendir()` does not do what you think it does. Read the docu.

For opening an output file in a specific directory use a path with `fopen()`.